# How to change file of Flat File Source in a SSIS Package by code in C#?

Tags: c#, ssis

I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I can't find something recently made that helps me do this. I know its not a good question but maybe a short answer in the right direction? What to look at to accomplish this?

Comment: what is the overall objective? is this a once off, a once in a while, or a frequent task your looking to complete? Im not 100% sure, but you'd probably be better off looking at doing all this in though SQL Server Data Import Export Tools and setting it as a regular task

Comment: I am creating a C# application. I'm just using SSIS packages to import big CSV files into a database, because it does this most efficient. I want to have one SSIS package and be able to edit the flat file source file path in my C# code.

Comment: the links below should help you out then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this link which should help you get your project off the ground too.

[MSDN LInk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135946.aspx)

this link also provides a step by step solution

[Step by Step Guide](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/on-the-fringe/2013/08/25/creating-and-executing-an-ssis-package-programmatically/)

hopefully this will be enough to get you started

Comment: Thanks, this is something yes :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at configurations. Basically, what you do is set the connection string for the file connection to a variable. Then you use the configuration to determine the file location at runtime. The C# code could update the configuration with the new value just before running the SSIS package. There are multiple ways  to do configuration and they cary by version of SSIS that you are using, so I can't go further into how to set up the configuration, you need to read through the manual for that.